# UIInterfaceOrientationUnknown for what purpose

Tags: objective-c, device-orientation, ios8

In iOS 8 they have added device orientation detection for `UIInterfaceOrientationUnknown` (Check the pre-release documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/UIInterfaceOrientationUnknown))

> - UIInterfaceOrientationUnknown
>
>   The orientation of the device cannot be determined.
>
>   Available in iOS 8.0 and later.

```
typedef enum : NSInteger { 
    UIInterfaceOrientationUnknown = UIDeviceOrientationUnknown, 
    UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait = UIDeviceOrientationPortrait, 
    UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown = UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown, 
    UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft = UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight, 
    UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight = UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft 
} UIInterfaceOrientation;
```

The way I see it there are only 4 ways the device could possibly ever been `Portrait`, `UpsideDown`, `LandscapeRight` and `LandscapeLeft`. So in what circumstances would you ever have a device orientation of unknown?

Comment: Maybe if the device does not have a gyro inside ... Or if the device is currently rotating (while animating) ... Or maybe if the app is running via CarPlay ... Or for a future device which doesn't support multiple screen orientations ... Just wild speculations, sorry ;)

Comment: @HAS at this moment in time I am happy with wild speculation as well.

Comment: Maybe if the phone is at the table laying flat. No rotation is recognized yet. Or could be possible to other future devices (Apple Watch?)

Comment: I would support the previous opinions on CarPlay and devices like the Apple Watch.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the `UIInterfaceOrientationUnknown` state when window creation was performed before `UIApplication` prepared and called `applicationDidLaunch` on appDelegate.

BTW, It was achieved by some swizzling magic inside the Typhoon DI framework.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen `UIInterfaceOrientationUnknown` multiple times, for example, when the device was exactly in the position between portrait and landscape (so it was not sure which orientation is the correct one).